# Ohana Support for sfdcfox

Tags: support

[sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) does a great deal for our community and is currently in need of some support.

Please offer whatever help you can in helping him overcome the [heat](https://www.gofundme.com/fear-heat-relief)

Note: I did reach out to Brian to confirm that this request is legit and he has in no way asked me to post in SFSE meta. I did it on my own wish.

Answer (score 10):

Sfdcfox has contributed not only on SFSE but to whole Salesforce ecosystem with his selfless work. I have donated what I could, I urge others who can donate to support such legend.

Comment: I kind of answers he has provided in this forum, even paid consultants wouldn't give such high quality answers.